# RTK Query api.utils not declared or _ref3 is undefined

Tags: rtk-query

I'm using RTK Query and have hit a snag with onQueryStarted, in particularly with the api.util object. Here's the endpoint:

```
sendLogout: builder.mutation({
            query: () => ({
                url: '/auth/logout',
                method: 'POST'
            }),
            async onQueryStarted(arg, {dispatch, queryFulfilled}) {
                console.log("onquerystarted")
                try {
                    await queryFulfilled
                    dispatch(logOut())
                    dispatch(api.util.resetApiState())
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            }
        }),
```

This works fine on my localhost, however I get a reference error that api is undefined. As far as I can tell from the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#resetapistate), there is no need to declare it. Now, without declaring it, when I go to build the image for the app, it fails since the reference error is being thrown. I tried declaring api in the args for onQueryStarted- (arg, api, {dispatch, queryFulfilled}), but then this throws a _ref3 is undefined error. The error does not show up in eslint, so I cannot just tell it to ignore the error, which I tried anyway...

I'm curious if anyone else has come across this and has a solution. Since its not declared in the docs, and since I cannot find anyone else asking it, perhaps there's something else I missed that would resolve it. Thanks

Comment: You can try to do something like `if (typeof api !== “undefined”)`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe. What is `api` in your code? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve].

Comment: Had similar issue with middleware running before createSlice this is not happening in dev tho